# Problems with ui-router and its links on Heroku

Tags: angularjs, heroku, angular-ui-router

I am having problems with the ui-sref directive (rarely) when deploying to Heroku. The application is working properly locally. I am using angular 1.6.8, ui-router 1.0 and I cannot figure out how to solve the issue.

My config.js file looks like this:

```
materialAdmin
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

        $stateProvider

            .state('not-authorised', {
                url: '/not-authorised',
                templateUrl: '404.html'
            })

            //------------------------------
            // LOGIN
            //------------------------------
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
            })

            ...

            $locationProvider
                .html5Mode(false)
                .hashPrefix('');

    }]);
```

**EDIT**: I am able to reproduce it locally if I run grunt build in production mode. I am a bit lost right now, but suspecting about the minification of the files.

This are the errors I am getting on the console: 
[image: Errors]

Answer (score 0):

dashboard should be a defined route if you are going to use it with ui-sref=""

Comment: Dashboard is a defined route inside the router. I have pasted just a snippet of the config file (see the dots).

Comment: You probably need to post more code for help, can't see anything wrong with the above the way it is...